# XML to XSLT pattern doesn't match

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am playing around with XSLT for a small task.
I have the following XML:

```
 <PFeed>
  <PID> MyProcess </PID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <MetaData>
      <Id> MyMetadataId </Id>
  </MetaData>
 <AllFeeds>
   <FeedContent>
      <Id> FeedContentId </Id>
   </FeedContent>
 </AllFeeds>
</PFeed>
```

I want to extract `FeedContentId` as text from this XML.

This is the XSLT code I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />
  <xsl:template match="/PFeed/AllFeeds/FeedContent">
        <xsl:value-of select="Id"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But instead of outputting `FeedContentId` I get the following: 
`MyProcess 1 MyMetadataId FeedContentId`

Can you please point out what I am missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of your current XSLT code is:

```
MyProcess 1 MyMetadataId FeedContentId
```

which is all the text inside the input XML document. This is because there is only one template in your stylesheet, and it does not apply to everything in the input document. For a part of the input, the XSLT processor has to resort to predefined *default templates*.

The default template for elements skips elements, the default template for text nodes *copies* those text nodes, and that's exactly what happens.

A solutions is to directly target the content you are interested in (`/PFeed/AllFeeds/FeedContent/Id`) with one template and write another template that matches text nodes:

```
<xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

to override the default behaviour for text nodes.

Also, if your output format is plain text, you should use

```
<xsl:output method="text"/>
```

and possibly get rid of extra spaces:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 

  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/PFeed/AllFeeds/FeedContent/Id">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Text Output**

```
 FeedContentId
```

---

Try this solution online [here](http://xsltransform.net/ej9EGcE).

Answer (score 2):

You first need a template to match the root element, then match what's inside. This XSLT now works again. (Test e.g. on http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/PFeed">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="AllFeeds/FeedContent"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="FeedContent">
      <xsl:value-of select="Id"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output after transformation:

```
FeedContentId
```

However, the same thing (getting the `/PFeed/AllFeeds/FeedContent/Id` node) could also be achieved by evaluating the above simple XPath expression.

Comment: This XSLT stylesheet does _not_ work. `xsl:value-of` cannot be inside `xsl:apply-templates`. Please test your code before submitting it as an answer.

Comment: It did work on the above specified testing page, though. Anyways, since OP uses the xpath expression, the XSLT doesn't matter. I'll add a note that it's broken.

Comment: This code is _always_ broken. If this works, the implementation of XSLT is incorrect. Never trust anything on w3schools.com, here is a reliable alternative: http://xsltransform.net/.